# Find the sum$\pmod{1000}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Find $$1\cdot 2 - 2\cdot 3 + 3\cdot 4 - \cdots + 2015 \cdot 2016 \pmod{1000}$$

I first tried factoring,

$$2(1 - 3 + 6 - 10 + \cdots + 2015 \cdot 1008)$$

I know that $\pmod{1000}$ is the last three digits.

$$= 2 - 6 + 12 - 20 + 30 - 42 + \cdots + 240$$

that is too complicated. **Just hints please!**

Comment: $a_1=-4 $
$d=-4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given series is: $$\sum_{i=1} ^{1008} (2i-1)(2i)-\sum_{i=1} ^{1007}(2i)(2i+1)$$ which is $$4\times\sum_{i=1} ^{1008} i^2-2\times \sum_{i=1} ^{1008} i-4\times \sum_{i=1} ^{1007} i^2+2\times \sum_{i=1} ^{1007} i$$ which, by cancelling out the common terms becomes, $$4\times 1008^2-2\times 1008=2\times 1008\times (2\times 1008-1)=2\times 1008\times 2015$$ which $\pmod {1000}$ is $$2\times 8\times 15=240.$$

Comment: @Amad27, hope the solution is clear.

Comment: excellent solution simply

Comment: @Amad27, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the sum exactly, by considering two terms at a time. 
Each two term is of the form $$(-2*2*k)$$ for $$k = 1, 2, 3 ...$$

Comment: I dont understand still though. (+1)

Comment: 1*2-2*3 ＝-2*(3-1) = -2*2; 3*4-4*5 = -4*(5-3) = -4*2; 5*6-6*7 = -6*(7-5) = -6*2...